# Owl carousel - Synced Owls - big images

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I need help for owl carousel - synced owls.

I want to use it in left column. but i can't hide other big imagesexcept main big image. It is overflow on right column and outside the container.

Other thing is how can i make it auto change images ?

I am waiting for helps. Thanks.

Here is link : [codepen](http://codepen.io/erenesto/pen/zqKZKq)

```
codepen.io/erenesto/pen/zqKZKq
```

Comment: You want to change other slider slide as other changes; let say if you change top slider bottom slider should move to same slide top slider just moved right?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code you use owl carousel v1.3.2 js and CSS v2.0.
So USe [OWL CSS V1.3.2](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css) Instead of [Owl CSS V2.0](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css).

Answer (score 0):

Im not really good coder, hardly now any code. But adding overflow:hidden to colum1 helps. Now you just need to work on your margins and padding:

```
.col-1 {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```